# SDL window seemingly improperly being marked 'unresponsive' by OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sdl, d, derelict3

I have an SDL2 windowed window accessed via Derelict 3.

It is supposed to strobe black and white (not because I hate epileptics), and it does this successfully. However, after a certain period of time, Ubuntu 13.10 marks the window as 'unresponsive', grays it out, and dulls the strobe effect.

This is highly irritating and totally kills the effect required by the application for visual stimulation to retrieve SSVEP readings from my EEG headset.

How do I get my OS to realize that the window is doing exactly what it should be doing?

### Code

As I have wrapped the SDL calls in my actual code, I'm going to provide pseudo-code and the SDL methods called in those sections (I've checked that I'm *not* calling any other SDL functions):

```
make a window using SDL_CreateWindow (no set flags)
make a renderer using SDL_CreateRenderer (with presentvsync flag set)
for( ... )
{
  fill screen black using SDL_RenderFillRect and SDL_SetRenderDrawColor
  update screen using SDL_RenderPresent
  fill screen white (same as above filling)
  update screen (same as above update)
}
exit
```

I pedantically check error codes and return values for all SDL calls in the wrapper lib. They're all fine. What I need to know is what I must add to provide the heartbeat to my OS so it stops graying out my window.

### Another thing...

Could someone please add an SDL2 tag? SDL2 has a very different API from SDL1.2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added event processing into the loop via `SDL_PollEvent(null)`. This satisfied the OS.

Comment: The exact same pattern of problem and resolution occurred for me on Windows (7, x64) too. Thanks for documenting the fix! It makes sense as both OSes must be sending 'heartbeat' type events to SDL and marking it as unresponsive if it doesn't consume them in any way.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to split the rendering code away from the event handling so that I can use SDL_WaitEvent instead of SDL_PollEvent. Creating both the window and the renderer in a seperate thread causes the problem in question, but creating the window in the main thread (same thread that ran SDL_Init, and is used for event handling) and the renderer in a different thread works. See [this](https://github.com/vheuken/SDL-Render-Thread-Example) for example (not my code).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Ubuntu 16.04 and SDL2.0x  - 
The solution that worked for me was:

```
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_X11_NET_WM_PING,"0");
```

set immediately after your SDL_Init(); call.
see : [SDL2 wiki here.](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_VIDEO_X11_NET_WM_PING?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryDefine%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryHints%29)